# Python: find the start index of a specific word number in a string

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring

I have this string:

```
myString = "Tomorrow will be very very rainy"
```

I would like to get the start index of the word number 5 (very).

What I do currently, I do split myString into words:

```
words = re.findall( r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', myString)
```

But I am not sure on how to get the start index of the word number 5: words[5].

Using the index() is not working as it finds the first occurrence:

```
start_index = myString.index(words[5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but loop through the list of split words and calculate the index based on the word length and the split character (in this case a space). This answer will target the fifth word in the sentence.

```
myString = "Tomorrow will be very very rainy"

target_word = 5

split_string = myString.split()

idx_start = 0

for i in range(target_word-1):
    idx_start += len(split_string[i])
    if myString[idx_start] == " ":
        idx_start += 1

idx_end = idx_start + len(split_string[target_word-1]) + 1

print(idx_start, idx_end, myString[idx_start:idx_end])
```

Comment: Thanks @speeder, I have edited my question as I do work in a slightly more complicated environment. I had to also mention it, sorry. The split I do is using the find with the regex, as I am splitting also using punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
wordnum = 5
l = [x.span()[1] for x in re.finditer(" +", string)]
pos = l[wordnum-2]
print(pos)
```

output

```
22
```

Comment: Thanks @Dominic, I have edited my question as I do work in a slightly more complicated environment. I had to also mention it, sorry. The split I do is using the find with the regex, as I am splitting also using punctuation, etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: Thank you Dominic but it seems the code is somehow not working. I will still add +1 as I opted for the solution @speeder1987 proposed with a slight adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

If only single spaces between words:

- Sum all word lengths before the wanted word
- Add amount of spaces

```
word_idx = 4  # zero based index
words = myString.split()
start_index = sum(len(word) for word in words[:word_idx]) + word_idx
```

Result:

```
22
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts with 5 words, you can match the first 4 words and capture the fifth one.

The you can use the `start` method and pass 1 to it for the first capture group of the [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start).

```
^(?:\w+\s+){4}(\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w+\s+){4}` Repeat 4 times matching 1+ word characters and 1+ whitspace chars
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word characters

Example

```
import re

myString = "Tomorrow will be very very rainy"
pattern = r"^(?:\w+\s+){4}(\w+)"
m = re.match(pattern, myString)
if m:
    print(m.start(1))
```

Output

```
22
```

---

For a broader match you can use `\S+` to match one or more non whitespace characters.

```
pattern = r"^(?:\S+\s+){4}(\S+)"
```